# TFS 2017 Build not compiling new .exe

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild, octopus-deploy

**Summary:**

The TFS 2017 Build I inherited is not compiling a new exe.

Any ideas on what to to review?

**More Detail**

A coworker set up a TFS Build and then totally jumped ship (Gave his 2weeks but then stopped coming into work.)

Anyway, he  set up a TFS 2017 Build and it runs successfully (no errors) but when I look at the deployment directory (We are using Octopus Deploy.) it has an older version of the exe (dated 10/11). It looks as though something is working since the .config file is being updated by Octopus.

I am very new to setting up a TFS Build so any ideas would be helpful.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.

The Version Numbers were not set up correctly.  Octopus Deploy was pulling an old version of the Package from 10/11 because that Version looked like the latest. However, it was not.

To resolve we deleted the old Packages in Octopus Deploy.

Comment: Thanks and Done.  At least I think so. Let me know if I miss understood your request.